# How to use setTimeout with puppeteer page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I was trying to run something every 100 milliseconds in puppeteer using page.evaluate, but when i run the code after setting the timeout nothing happens. I tried running in a non headless browser and even running setTimeout in the dev tools and nothing happened, what should I do to make the timeout actually run?

Here is the relevant code

```
await page.evaluate(async () => {
await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => console.log('timeout'), 100)
});
})
```

EDIT:
A bit more data, if i run page.evaluate(() => console.log('a')) it works, and when I run it in a non headless browser I see javascript is blocked

Comment: What purpose does it serve to wrap `setInterval` in a promise you never settle? That `await` will wait forever.

Comment: *"I tried running in a non headless browser and even running setTimeout in the dev tools and nothing happened"* If you ran that `setInterval` code in the browser devtools, it would definitely start logging "interval" every 100ms.

Comment: Thats why I am asking the question @T.J.Crowder it is not working, I tried running it again and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this (also, there was a typo in `setTiemout` in your code):

```js
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => { console.log('timeout'); resolve(); }, 100);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that did not work, and the typo was only in the question not the code, so that’s not the problem. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my issue and it was totally my mistake, if you are having issues of this kind just check that you are not disabling javascript in your code (I should have done that). The way you would be doing it would be page.setJavascriptEnabled(false).